# Bifurcation Diagram for system with no bifurcation point

Tags: nonlinear-system, bifurcation

I'm currently studying bifurcation points and diagrams for non-linear dynamical systems. One question that my lecturer has given, clearly does not have a bifurcation point and therefore no bifurcation. My question is how would you visualise this on a bifurcation diagram when there is no bifurcation point? The question is dx/dt = 1-ax^2. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Consider what happens if $a$ changes sign. Are you sure there aren't any bifurcation points?